# Is Adobe Air required on Android device to run Flash created APKs?

Tags: android, flash, device, apk

I was just wondering if the user that downloads my APK from Google Play needs to install Adobe Air on their device to be able to run the APK that was created in Flash?

Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app created in flash and published for Air for Android does need the Adobe Air runtime. As of Adobe Flash CS6, it is possible to package the runtime with the apk so there is no need for additional installations.